# PHP CLI on Win10 no longer loading local ini file after upgrade to 7.4

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I used to run PHP 5.6 on Win 10 in CLI mode. I had different php.ini files in different directories and PHP would always pick up the one in the current directory if one was there.

Now, after upgrading to PHP 7.4, PHP always loads the php.ini from where php.exe is installed.

I know that I can specify a different php.ini with the -c command line directive, but that's not convenient. Is there a way to restore the 5.6 behavior?

Additional info:
I'm seeing the same behavior change on the LINUX web server: local php.ini files that used to be loaded now get ignored. I was able to mostly solve it there by renaming them to .user.ini

Comment: According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/773201/423490), you may modify your registry to alter the ini's path.

Comment: Thanks, @KoalaYeung, I've seen the information about the registry. Doesn't solve my problem, though, because it only specifies one location. I'm working on multiple projects and each project needs a different php.ini. I have to be able to switch between projects quickly. Previously this was effortless.